# C# NPGSQL Connection is Busy

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I've got the following problem:

I'm using NPGSQL for the Connection to the Database. Furthermore I'm using Entity Framework Core.

This is how my Context looks like:

```
using System.IO;
using DatabaseLibrary.Models.Discount;
using DatabaseLibrary.Models.Gender;
using DatabaseLibrary.Models.Ranks;
using DatabaseLibrary.Models.Employee;
using DatabaseLibrary.Models.Items;
using DatabaseLibrary.Models.Settings;
using DatabaseLibrary.Models.Transaction;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace DatabaseLibrary
{
    // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
    public class PGSQLConnectionManager : DbContext
    {
        //Variables
        private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        //public PGSQLConnectionManager(DbContextOptions<PGSQLConnectionManager> options) : base(options)
        //{
        //    Configuration = (new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json").Build());
        //}

        public PGSQLConnectionManager()
        {
            Configuration = (new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json").Build());
        }

        public PGSQLConnectionManager(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        //Database
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(
                Configuration["ConnectionStrings:PGSQLConnectionManager"]
            );
        
        //Model Sets
        public DbSet<Gender> Gender { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Gender2Employee> Gender2Employee { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmployeeRank> EmployeeRank { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Item { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ItemType> ItemType { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ItemType2Item> ItemType2Items { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmployeeRank2Employee> EmployeeRank2Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transaction2Items> Transaction2Items { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TransactionNonItem> TransactionNonItem { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TaxSettings> TaxSettings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Discount> Discount { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Transaction2Discount> Transaction2Discount { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EmployeeRank2AspRole> EmployeeRank2AspRoles { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>().ToTable("Gender");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender2Employee>().ToTable("Gender2Employee");
            modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeRank>().ToTable("EmployeeRank");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employee");
            modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeRank2Employee>().ToTable("EmployeeRank2Employee");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable("Item");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ItemType>().ToTable("ItemType");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ItemType2Item>().ToTable("ItemType2Item");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>().ToTable("Transaction");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction2Items>().ToTable("Transaction2Items");
            modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionNonItem>().ToTable("TransactionNonItem");
            modelBuilder.Entity<TaxSettings>().ToTable("TaxSettings");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Discount>().ToTable("Discount");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction2Discount>().ToTable("Transaction2Discount");
            modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeRank2AspRole>().ToTable("EmployeeRank2AspRole");

            /*
             * Primary Key auto increment
             */
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender>()
                .Property(g => g.GenderId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender2Employee>()
                .Property(g => g.Gender2EmployeeId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
                .Property(i => i.ItemId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ItemType>()
                .Property(it => it.ItemTypeId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<ItemType2Item>()
                .Property(iti => iti.ItemType2ItemId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeRank>()
                .Property(er => er.EmployeeRankId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeRank2Employee>()
                .Property(ere => ere.EmployeeRank2EmployeeId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
                .Property(t => t.TransactionId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction2Items>()
                .Property(ti => ti.Transaction2ItemsId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionNonItem>()
                .Property(tni => tni.TransactionId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<TaxSettings>()
                .Property(ts => ts.TaxSettingsId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Discount>()
                .Property(d => d.DiscountId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction2Discount>()
                .Property(t2d => t2d.Transaction2DiscountId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();
            modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeRank2AspRole>()
                .Property(e2a => e2a.EmployeeRank2AspRoleId)
                .UseIdentityColumn();

            /*
             * Relations
             */
            //Gender
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender2Employee>()
                .HasOne<Employee>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.EmployeeId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.EmployeeId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gender2Employee>()
                .HasOne<Gender>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(g => g.GenderId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(g => g.GenderId);

            //item
            modelBuilder.Entity<ItemType2Item>()
                .HasOne<Item>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.ItemId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(i => i.ItemId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ItemType2Item>()
                .HasOne<ItemType>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.ItemTypeId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(i => i.ItemTypeId);
            
            //transaction
            //transaction2items
            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction2Items>()
                .HasOne<Transaction>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.TransactionId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.TransactionId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction2Items>()
                .HasOne<Item>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.ItemId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(i => i.ItemId);
            //transaction2discount
            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction2Discount>()
                .HasOne<Transaction>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.TransactionId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.TransactionId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction2Discount>()
                .HasOne<Discount>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.DiscountId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(d => d.DiscountId);
            
            //employeerank2asproleid
            modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeRank2AspRole>()
                .HasOne<EmployeeRank>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(er => er.EmployeeRankId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(er => er.EmployeeRankId);
        }
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs I'm adding the context to the dependency injection like this:

```
//Database initialization
            services.AddDbContext<PGSQLConnectionManager>(options => 
             options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PGSQLConnectionManager")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
```

Now since my latest additional query I was using the Context like this:

In any .razor file I'm injecting the PGSQLConnectionManager:

```
@inject PGSQLConnectionManager Context
```

And later on in the .razor file in the @code part, I use the injected Context like this:

```
GetEmployee getAllEmployees = new GetEmployee(Context);
```

And every Class that needs a database connection is getting initialized like this:

```
    public class GetEmployee
    {
        //Variables
        private readonly PGSQLConnectionManager _connectionManager;

        public GetEmployee(PGSQLConnectionManager context)
        {
            _connectionManager = context;
        }

        public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
        {
            try
            {
                //query all employees
                List<Employee> allEmployees = _connectionManager.Employee.AsQueryable().ToList();
                return allEmployees;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                #I know this is bad, but reporting is to come
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

And now, that I've done this like, >20 times I get an error: **Connection is Busy**

I tried using a static class and reference the PGSQLConnectionManager in there once, but then everytime I try to get the Context I get an error, that the Object has been disposed??? and can't get accessed anymore.
As far as I know, objects do not get disposed if they are in a static class.
I couldn't find where the database gets disposed in the static class thing.

So far, I think I'm using EntityFramework or the NPGSQL wrong. But I cannot find a good example, that represents my case.

Thanks ahead for any help

Comment: Don't you need to call the constructor? PGSQLConnectionManager _connectionManager = new PGSQLConnectionManager();

Comment: A new object seems wrong to me. Why would I create a new object everytime I need the database connection. Why shouldn't I use one major object and reuse this one with it's connections getting closed after each insert or update.

Comment: You need to call just once in project when it starts to fill the dbContext with data from the database.  Otherwaise the model has no data.

Comment: That's what I'm doing with dependency Injection. But that's getting me to this error.

Comment: No you are not.  You need to use "NEW".